# Timline datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker, timeline

I'm looking for a timeline date picker with javascript. ( jquery or boostrap plugin)

something similar to this https://earthdata.nasa.gov/labs/worldview/ it's a open source project in github but i can't seem to find what they used to do that.

Answer (score 0):

When I looked at the page source, I saw they were referencing mobiscroll.min.css and mobiscroll.min.js. I did a Google search and I found this: http://demo.mobiscroll.com/calendar